# Css3 Transition dont work on ios

Tags: html, ios, css

On PC and android devices is my Transition Code work but on iOS devices it will not work. Im only use html and css.

```
/***** BOX 3 *****/
#box3 {
height:240px;
width:198px;
border:1px solid #dedede;
background-color:#fcfcfc;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
margin-right:23px;
margin-bottom:23px;
opacity:1;
-webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
-o-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
-ms-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}

#box3:hover {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #999;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #999;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px #999;
}

#box3 .bgbox3 {
background:url(images/top-seller-3.jpg) 50% 10% no-repeat;
position:absolute;
height:240px;
width:198px;
opacity:1;
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out-in;
-moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#box3:hover .bgbox3 {
opacity:0.3;
}

#box3 a, #box3 a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}

.imagebox3 {
background: url(images/bestellen.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
position:absolute;
height:40px;
width:40px;
opacity:0;
margin-top:80px;
margin-left:10px;
-webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
-moz-transition: all .2s linear;
-o-transition: all .2s linear;
-ms-transition: all .2s linear;
transition: all .2s linear;
}

#box3:hover .imagebox3 {
opacity:1;
-webkit-transform:translate(45px ,0);
transform:translate(45px ,0);
}
```

Thanks a lot
Regards Timur

Comment: Add your html so we can see what this is being applied to. Also try recreating your issue on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: How do you do `:hover` on a touch device?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/collexdesign/3kquf5sy/1/

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, try using the `:active` selector along with `:focus`?

The most reliable way to go about this is to put these attributes in and get rid of the CSS part:

`<div id="box3" ontouchstart="this.setAttribute('style','-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 3px #999;')" ontouchend="this.setAttribute('style','')">`

`Ontouchstart` is the official iOS/Android/webkit version of `onmousedown`. And it actually fires the instant someone touches the screen, whereas mouse events have the longpress-detection delay.

Another thing, you could just set `this.style.boxShadow` directly instead, but from experience that shadows do not like to render when set programatically, so setting the attribute from scratch forces a re-draw.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, my english is not so good.
i have now input my code to fiddle.
do you can help me here with input the code?